# Read configuration for language in vscode (set by setLanguageConfiguration)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am debugging a VS Code extension and think perhaps there is a race condition where another extension might be over-riding some of the configuration I have set on `activate` via:

```ts
setLanguageConfiguration(language: string, configuration: LanguageConfiguration): Disposable
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#languages

Is there an API to read the current state of language configuration? (doing so would allow me to check the `wordPattern` for my language which I have a hunch may being changed by some other code)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such API at the moment, but there is a long-standing feature request for one you can vote for:

[Allow extensions to get a LanguageConfiguration for a language (#2871)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/2871)